# Revit API: Material Asset Parameters get and set

Tags: revit-api

I am trying to access via RevitAPI the data that is contained for particular asset. For instance I want to manipulate the Identity Data and get and eventually set some data for Manufacturer, Model, Cost and URL. 
How can I achieve the same for the other Assets?

[image]

I am reading the Materials:

```
public IEnumerable<Material> GetMaterials(Document doc)
    {
        collector = new FilteredElementCollector(doc);

        return collector.OfClass(typeof(Material)).OfType<Material>();
    }
```

And then the Parameters:

```
public IEnumerable<Parameter> GetMaterialParameters(Material material)
    {
        List<Parameter> parameters = new List<Parameter>();
        var localParameters = material.ParametersMap;

        foreach (Parameter localParameter in localParameters)
        {
            parameters.Add(localParameter);
        }

        return parameters;
    }
```

but still can't find where those properties are exposed.

Answer (score 0):

What you really need is the Visual Materials API that was introduced in Revit 2018.1, the newest update:

- [Revit 2018.1 and the Visual Materials API](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2017/08/revit-20181-and-the-visual-materials-api.html)

It is much harder and maybe impossible to achieve what you want in earlier versions.

Here are pointers to some more or less futile attempts:

- [Material Assets and FBX](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2011/01/material-assets-and-fbx.html)
- [Read Material Asset Parameter](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2013/01/read-material-asset-parameter.html)
- [Rendering Assets](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2016/05/roomedit3d-console-test-and-rendering-assets.html)
- [Material Asset Textures](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2016/10/list-material-asset-texture-and-forge-webinar-recordings.html)

Comment: Thank you. But I can't find any samples. Is there any?

Answer (score 0):

Finally this is how I managed to edit the parameters.

```
private void AssignProductData_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var material = (MaterialItem)MaterialsCombo.SelectedItem;

        using (var transaction = new Transaction(doc))
        {
            transaction.Start("ChangeName");

            var parameterManufacturer = material.Material.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.ALL_MODEL_MANUFACTURER);
            parameterManufacturer.Set("Brand New Product");

            var parameterCost = material.Material.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.ALL_MODEL_COST);
            parameterCost.Set(1099.99);

            var parameterModel = material.Material.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.ALL_MODEL_MODEL);
            parameterModel.Set("R1223123KJNSDAS9089");

            var parameterUrl = material.Material.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.ALL_MODEL_URL);
            parameterUrl.Set("http://www.site.no/products/R1223123KJNSDAS9089");

            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
```